# Модуль Apache mod_status не работает из-за Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

Помогите пожалуйста, в очень не простом модуле *Апача*.

Не могу заставить работать модуль *mod_status*

Делал все по [этой](http://goo.gl/aHXt3y) и [этой инструкции](http://goo.gl/xYPjV3).

Модуль *mod_status* установил. Но при выполнении команды

```
apache2ctl fullstatus
```

или `http://localhost/server-status` или `http://ip-адрес сервера/server-status` всегда пишет одно и то же: `404 Not found Nginx`

Интуитивно догадываюсь, что *nginx* получает запрос, но не передает его apache.

Может, нужно где-то какой-то порт поменять?

А может, нужно как то, заставить *Apache* обрабатывать страницу `http://localhost/server-status`, минуя *nginx*.

---

Вот выдержка из моей конфигурации.

ОС *Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS*

В качестве Фронт-энд сервера: *nginx/1.4.6*

Вот пример его конфига (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*;
    server {

        server_name localhost;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
        listen 80;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;

        location @fallback {


            error_log /dev/null crit;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            access_log off ;
        }

    } # server

}
```

В качестве Бэк-энд сервера: *Apache/2.4.7*

Вот пример его конфига (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`):

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
Include conf.d/
Include vhosts-default/
Include vhosts/

# подключаем настройки пхп май админа
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

#NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# Listen: Позволяет привязать Apache к конкретному адресу IP, и/или порту, в
# дополнение к порту, определенному по умолчанию. См. также директиву
# <VirtualHost>.

Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
#NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:*
#NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Пример конфигурации одного сайта.
`/etc/apache2/vhosts/tfox/mysite.com`

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName mysite.com


    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>

        SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback
        SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" loopback
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.access.log combined env=!loopback

    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.error.log   


</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/tfox/data/www/mysite.com>
    php_admin_flag engine on
    Options -ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Настройки модуля mod_status

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
    # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
    # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
    # Uncomment and change the "192.0.2.0/24" to allow access from other hosts.

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    #Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
</Location>

    # Keep track of extended status information for each request
    ExtendedStatus On

    # Determine if mod_status displays the first 63 characters of a request or
    # the last 63, assuming the request itself is greater than 63 chars.
    # Default: Off
    #SeeRequestTail On


    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        # Show Proxy LoadBalancer status in mod_status
        ProxyStatus On
    </IfModule>


</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 1):

порекомендую попробовать изменить в конфигурации `nginx` две строки:

```
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
```

замените на

```
proxy_redirect off;
```

и

```
location @fallback {
```

замените на

```
location / {
```